# how sobel edge detector as a first order derivative is turned to a 2 dim filter?

Tags: image-processing, edge-detection, gradient

I want to know theorem behind sobel operator. basically a first order derivative is -1/2 0 1/2 . its a vector. the question is how this vector is turned to a matrix below and what was theory and reason behind that?
-1 0 1;
-2 0 2;
-1 0 1;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Background

The Sobel edge detector was introduced back in 1968 by Irwin Sobel and Gary Feldman as the Sobel-Feldman operator. In broad strokes, 'edges' in images are related to gradients, which motivated their development of a discrete differentiation operator. The Sobel-Feldman operator only computes an approximation of the gradient and not the actual gradient. However, this integer valued operator is simple and fast, which makes it useful.

> Directionality

The Sobel-Feldman operator is only capable of estimating gradients along mutually perpendicular directions separately and not jointly. Since an image is typically a matrix itself, the operator provides gradients along rows and gradients along columns. **This limitation is important since we will use this property to extend the operator to multiple dimensions.**

> Matrix Decomposition

The Sobel-Feldman operator in 2 dimensions is given as a kernel matrix. For image matrix $\mathcal{I}$, the Gradient operator (Sobel edge detector) for x- and y- directions is given as:

$\mathbf {G} _{x}={\begin{bmatrix}+1&0&-1\\+2&0&-2\\+1&0&-1\end{bmatrix}}*\mathbf {\mathcal{I}} \quad {\mbox{and}}\quad \mathbf {G} _{y}={\begin{bmatrix}+1&+2&+1\\0&0&0\\-1&-2&-1\end{bmatrix}}*\mathbf {\mathcal{I}} $

Sobel kernels can be decomposed as the products of an averaging and a differentiation kernel. For example,

$\mathbf {G} _{x}= {\begin{bmatrix}+1&0&-1\\+2&0&-2\\+1&0&-1\end{bmatrix}}={\begin{bmatrix}1\\2\\1\end{bmatrix}}{\begin{bmatrix}+1&0&-1\end{bmatrix}}$

This is the key idea in extending the Sobel operator from 1-D vector to 2-D matrix. The operator uses a triangle-kernel for averaging (smoothing) in the direction perpendicular to the desired gradient direction and the Sobel differentiator in the desired direction.

> Higher Dimensions

Sobel–Feldman filters for image derivatives in different dimensions with $x,y,z,t\in \left\{0,-1,1\right\}$:

vector: $h_{x}'(x)=h'(x); h_{x}'(x)=h'(x)$

matrix: $h_{x}'(x,y)=h'(x)h(y) h_{x}'(x,y)=h'(x)h(y)$

Tensor: $h_{x}'(x,y,z)=h'(x)h(y)h(z) h_{x}'(x,y,z)=h'(x)h(y)h(z)$

Tensor:  $h_{x}'(x,y,z,t)=h'(x)h(y)h(z)h(t) h_{x}'(x,y,z,t)=h'(x)h(y)h(z)h(t)$

> Tensor Sobel operator

For 3-D (x,y,z), the Sobel-Feldman operator in z-direction is:

$h_{z}'(:,:,-1)={\begin{bmatrix}+1&+2&+1\\+2&+4&+2\\+1&+2&+1\end{bmatrix}}\quad h_{z}'(:,:,0)={\begin{bmatrix}0&0&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}}\quad h_{z}'(:,:,1)={\begin{bmatrix}-1&-2&-1\\-2&-4&-2\\-1&-2&-1\end{bmatrix}}$

> Summary

1. The Sobel operator is only a poor approximation of gradient using a center-difference operator.
2. The operator is only informative about 1 direction at a time.
3. The operator is extended to higher dimensions by using a triangle shaped averaging filter for other perpendicular directions (dimensions).
4. There isn't a deep theoretical reasoning behind this operator. It is a discretized version of a differential (gradient) and Gaussian filter (smoothing). But it is simple and fast.